# How can I use storyboards for my file browser project on ios5?

Tags: ios5, dropbox

I am trying to find a solution for browsing a remote file system (dropbox) by using storyboards. For example if user taps to browsing folders there is no information about how deep is the folder structure. I mean the folder may contain another folder and another may contain another inside and it can go to 5, 10, 20 etc. This makes impossible to define how many tableview controllers should i add my storyboard. I tried to use only one and updated the same tableview for each selected folder with the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
[dropBoxArray removeAllObjects]; //remove all the objects which comes from the previous folder structure 


[[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/selected folder/"]; // load the newly selected folder 
    contents

}
```

It works just for one direction, the user can browse the folder tree until forever, but this time it is impossible to go back step by step. Because the navigation controller puts the back button on the navigation item and it loads the previous view instead of the upper directory.
I could not find how can I handle this logic properly and needed help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your back button action method, back button pops last view from stack so it may not work in your case, and add a next button also (or use didselect row whatever works for you)

Second use singleton class to keep your folder path.

So next will add lets say a detail folder to your metadata path `selected folder/detail folder` and back will remove the last path `selected folder/`

Add singleton a singleton class to your code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SingletonClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *lastCreatedFolderName;
    NSMutableArray *fileListForEdit;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastCreatedFolderName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *fileListForEdit;
+ (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance;

@end

    #import "SingletonClass.h"

    @implementation SingletonClass

    @synthesize lastCreatedFolderName=_lastCreatedFolderName;
    @synthesize fileListForEdit=_fileListForEdit;

    + (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance
    {
        static SingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedInstance = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
            // Do any other initialisation stuff here
        });
        return sharedInstance;
    }

    - (id)init {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            _lastCreatedFolderName = @"Empty Folder";
            _fileListForEdit=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        }
        return self;
    }
  -(NSString *) addFolderPath : (NSString *) nextFolder{


    [_fileListForEdit addObject:nextFolder]; // add your folder path to mutablearray 
    for(int i=0 ; int<[_fileListForEdit count]; i++) {
         _lastCreatedFolderName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_lastCreatedFolderName,[_fileListForEdit objectAtIndex:i]]; //add folder path to your current path

     }

     return _lastCreatedFolderName;
} 
-(NSString *) removeLastFolderDromPath
{
     [_fileListForEdit removeLastObject];// remove last folder path from array

     //create new folder path
     for(int i=0 ; int<[_fileListForEdit count]; i++) {
         _lastCreatedFolderName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_lastCreatedFolderName,[_fileListForEdit objectAtIndex:i]]; //add folder path to your current path

     }

     return _lastCreatedFolderName;
}


    @end
```

In -(void)loadView:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;

   UIBarButtonItem *btnNext = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnNext;

-(void)backPressed: (id)sender
{
    //call your singleton here and load last path
    SingletonClass *sharedInstance=[SingletonClass sharedInstance];
    NSString *destDirectory= [sharedInstance addFolderPath :@"nextFolder"];

}
 -(void)nextPressed: (id)sender
{
  //call your singleton here and load last path
  //get last created file name from singleton
    SingletonClass *sharedInstance=[SingletonClass sharedInstance];
    NSString *destDirectory= [sharedInstance removeLastFolderDromPath];//gives you the new path
}
```

then just call your client with

`[[self restClient] loadMetadata:destDirectory];`

**Note that this call is not tested you may see some typos and need to edit code little bit**